# Reindex from both remote and local cluster in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, bigdata, cluster-computing, reindex

I have "index_a" on a remote elasticsearch cluster that looks like this:

```
{
   _index: "index_a",
   _type: "_doc",
   _id: "1",
   _score: 1,
   _source: {
      customer_id: "1234",
      customer_name: "spider",
      message: "does what ever"
   }
}, 
{
   _index: "index_a",
   _type: "_doc",
   _id: "2",
   _score: 1,
   _source: {
      customer_id: "3333",
      customer_name: "pig",
      message: "spider-pid does"
   }
}
```

And I Also have "index_a" (yes, it's the same name!) on the current elasticsearch cluster that i'm performing the _reindex to, that looks like this:

```
{
   _index: "index_a",
   _type: "_doc",
   _id: "2",
   _score: 1,
   _source: {
      customer_id: "3333",
      customer_name: "pig",
      message: "spider-pid does"
   }
},
{
   _index: "index_a",
   _type: "_doc",
   _id: "3",
   _score: 1,
   _source: {
      customer_id: "9876",
      customer_name: "coronavirus",
      message: "stay safe and at home"
   }
}
```

as you can see there are duplications docs from the first "index_a" above, but there is also new data there that I wanna keep!

Eventually what I wanna end up with, in my current elasticsearch cluster is this index_b:

```
{
   _index: "index_b",
   _type: "_doc",
   _id: "1",
   _score: 1,
   _source: {
      customer_id: "1234",
      customer_name: "spider",
      message: "does what ever"
   }
}, 
{
   _index: "index_b",
   _type: "_doc",
   _id: "2",
   _score: 1,
   _source: {
      customer_id: "3333",
      customer_name: "pig",
      message: "spider-pid does"
   }
},
{
   _index: "index_b",
   _type: "_doc",
   _id: "3",
   _score: 1,
   _source: {
      customer_id: "9876",
      customer_name: "coronavirus",
      message: "stay safe and at home"
   }
}
```

So basically I know for a **fact** that I could reach this result in **two** different
_reindex requests, 1st _reindex will be from the remote cluster index_a to the current elasticsearch cluster index_b.
And the 2nd _reindex will be from the current elasticsearch cluster index_a to the current cluster index_b. 
but running those two _reindex request is **VERY wasteful** in terms of big data,
cause what the request does is basically run over each doc-id one by one and wrtie/override it.

when trying to do this on a single _reindex request, I've tried this:

*POST http://current_cluster/_reindex*

```
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://remote_cluster/"
    },
    "index": ["index_a-from-remote", "index_a-of-current"] //renamed them to be more understood for you
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index_b"
  }
}
```

and the response indicates that there is no "index_a-of-current" in the remote cluster and it makes sense: it has happened because this type of _reindex request is built to only get indices from a remote elasticsearch cluster.

so my question is:

is there a way to perform a single _reindex request that would take both "index_a" from the remote cluster, and also "index_a" of the current cluster, and will reindex them both to "index_b" at the current cluster?

I would be happy if anyone cloud shed any light on this matter as I've tried a bunch of other stuff in the request and read the Reindex API documentation and didn't found an answer yet. 
tnx for any help!

Comment: Running two reindex requests or a single one (not possible in this case) would perform the exact same job, i.e. going over each document in both clusters. So if you have 1000 docs in your local cluster and 1000 docs in your remote cluster, running a single reindex request on both cluster or two reindex requests (one per cluster) would still have to go over 2000 documents.

Comment: @Val you are right, so I guess to have less code for a cleaner class, I would just index to "index_a"(the remote) into "index_a"(of the local) and then I would end up with "index_a" which is the same (content-wise) as what I wanted to have in "index_b" in the end. tnx!